# React: adding ternary operator for component breaks progress bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still learning React and am trying to parse text from an API call into json objects while displaying progress in a progress bar.

Below, Home.js uses useEffect hook to

- call getData that grabs (lots of) API text data
- call parseText to parse returned text
- call parseSeriesId to parse returned results
- set seriesIdParts

Finally, seriesIdParts is passed to Occupation.js as props. That works fine and working code is displayed below.

My problem is that I want to make the progress bar disappear when parseText is finished. I found a post that did it using a ternary operator, so trying that I changed this:

```
<ProgressBar percentage={percentage}/>
```

to this:

```
{percentage >= 100 ? console.log("Done.") : <ProgressBar percentage={percentage}/>
```

and now the progressBar disappears, but it no longer populates green. I can log the percentage value just fine in both ProgressBar.js and Filler.js, so it seems to be that the Filler width element is not picking up the percentage value increment:

```
<div className="filler" style={{ width: `${percentage}%`}}>
```

How do I fix this?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Occupation from './Occupation';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

const Home = () => {    
    
    const [seriesIdParts, setSeriesIdParts] = useState([]);
    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);

    async function getData(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if( response.status !== 200 ) {
            throw new Error('Problem calling ' + url);
        }
        return response.text();
    }

    function parseSeriesId(data) {
        let results = new Set()
        data.forEach(function(value) {     
            let areaCode = value.seriesId.substring(4, 11);
            let industry = value.seriesId.substring(11, 17);
            let occupation = value.seriesId.substring(17, 23);
            let dataType = value.seriesId.substring(23, value.seriesId.length);
            let seriesIdVal = value.value;
            if( dataType === '04') {
                let result = {areaCode: areaCode, industry: industry, occupation: occupation, dataType: dataType, seriesIdVal: seriesIdVal};
                results.add(result);
            }
        })
        return results;
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/oe/oe.data.0.Current')
        .then(data => {
            const parseText = function(data) {
                data = data.split('\n');
                let localNum = 1090;
                let results = new Set();
                let intervalAmount = 100 / localNum;
                
                for( let i=1; i<=localNum; i++ ) {
                    setPercentage((i * intervalAmount));

                    let line = data[i];
                    if( line !== "") {
                        line = line.split('\t');
                        let seriesIdValue = line[0].trim();
                        let valueValue = line[3].trim();
                        if (valueValue !== '-') {
                            results.add({'seriesId': seriesIdValue, 'value': valueValue});
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }
            return parseText(data, 100);
        })
        .then(data => {
            return parseSeriesId(data);
        })
        .then(data => {
            setSeriesIdParts(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [percentage]);

    return(
        <div className="homeComponent">
            <label id="parsetext" >
                Parsing Text...
                <ProgressBar percentage={percentage}/> 
            </label>
            {seriesIdParts && <Occupation seriesIdParts={seriesIdParts}/>}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

**ProgressBar.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Filler from './Filler';

const ProgressBar = ({percentage}) => {
    // console.log('Pbar: ', percentage);           <== Displays fine!
   return (  
        <div className="progressbar">
            <Filler percentage={percentage}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ProgressBar;
```

**Filler.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Filler = ({percentage}) => {
    return (  
        <div className="filler" style={{ width: `${percentage}%`}}>
           {console.log('filler: ' + percentage)}.  <== Displays fine!
        </div>
    );
}
export default Filler;
```

**Occupation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Occupation = ({seriesIdParts}) => {
    
    console.log('seriesIdParts in Occupation:', seriesIdParts.size)    <== Displays fine!

    //other code...
};
export default Occupation;
```

**App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.progressbar {
  margin: 4em auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.filler {
  height: inherit;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

#parsetext {
  text-align: 'center';
  margin: 4em 0 0;
}
```

UPDATE: If there is a better way to make the progress bar disappear, I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: try replacing the `console.log("Done.");` with `(console.log("Done.") || (<p>Done</p>))`.

Comment: I get a Done in the log and in HTML, but still no green bar fill.

Comment: ...with this: {percentage >= 100 ? (console.log("Done.") || (<p>Done</p>)) : <ProgressBar percentage={percentage}/> }

Comment: To make this question more answerable, please make it simpler. Right now you're sharing parsing logic, fetching, etc etc. Remove all that to isolate the issue, and if you don't find it yourself, someone here will be more likely to find than now. Give one or two components anyone can easily run and reason about.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the height of the `filler` class to like `20px` instead of `inherit` just to try?

```
.filler {
  height: inherit;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

I tried to test just that div and I couldn't see it with "inherit"

Comment: Tried the filler 20px height solution but no change.